# ProgressBar does not reflect value change C#

Tags: c#, xaml, progress-bar

I am new to XAML and c#, and I am trying to figure out how to update the progress bar.

I have the following code in XAML:

```
<Hyperlink Click="Launch_Click">Launch Program</Hyperlink>
<ProgressBar  x:Name="Progress1" x:Uid="Progress1" Minimum="0" Maximum="1" Value="0">
```

And the implementation of Launch_Click in C#

```
private void Launch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        Progress1.Value +=0.1;
    }

}
```

When I run debugger the Progress1.Value seems update correctly, but progress bar does not seem to reflect this change until execution Launch_Click finishes. How can I make progress bar reflect change as Progress1.Value updates?

Comment: Your loop will execute completely before the next refresh event draws the update. And even *if* it did refresh, the loop will complete extremely fast. There's only 100 iterations, which would complete in less than one millisecond.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the comment, I understand that the loop finishes extremely fast, but in debugger it is easy to see that progress bar is not updating. I think it has something to do with refresh event, b/c if I show message box in for loop progress bar is updated correctly. How do I refresh the event? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Asynchrony proves especially valuable for applications that access the UI thread because all UI-related activity usually shares one thread. If any process is blocked in a synchronous application, all are blocked. Your application stops responding, and you might conclude that it has failed when instead it's just waiting.

When you use asynchronous methods, the application continues to respond to the UI. You can resize or minimize a window, for example, or you can close the application if you don't want to wait for it to finish.

**The `async` and `await` keywords in C# are the heart of async programming**. By using those two keywords, you can use resources in the .NET Framework or the Windows Runtime to create an asynchronous method almost as easily as you create a synchronous method. Asynchronous methods that you define by using async and await are referred to as async methods.

**So all you need is change your code like this**

```
public async void button1_Click( object sender , EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        Progress1.Value +=1;
        await Task.Delay(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, could you give a little bit more information on how these tutorial ideas would apply to my problem? Sorry but I'm quite new to c# and XAML, so could you give me guidance an the general approach to solve my problem, and I would read the articles and apply them.Thanks!